# Getting an initializationError in cucmber Junit run

Tags: maven, cucumber-junit

When i am running a Junit test after successful configured Cucumber jar files, I am getting an error as initializationError.

I have added latest jars in the Libraries. Please refer below error and screenshot for more details.

[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO1tU.jpg)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;)Ljava/util/List;
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Runner Class Details:

```
package runnerTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin={"pretty", "html:target/html"},
        features= "src/test/resource/myFeature",
        glue={"Cucumber.MavenCucumerTest.Steps"}
 )
public class test {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the package name of the step definition in `glue` option.

```
glue={"Cucumber.MavenCucumerTest"}
```

Comment: Hello @kripindas, As per your input i have added package name of the step but till getting same error. 

Please refer screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/1ueeiMe 
Thank You!

Comment: @JalpeshPatel Please add the runner class details in the question. Also check Right clicking on the **Project Folder > Build path > Configure Build path > Projects tab**. If there is any Project listing there, delete that Project and execute the runner file.

Comment: In projects tab there are no any existing project. And also i have added my runner class in the question. Please refer screenshot https://imgur.com/a/1ueeiMe